# Atmel Studio 7 : using avr/delay.h header file is giving warning

Tags: atmelstudio

I am working on a white line follower code in atmel studio 7 and added a lcd.c file to display the sensed values for white line. The header files used are

```
<avr/io.h>                 
<avr/delay.h>         
<util/delay.h>
```

in both the main file and lcd file.
**when i compile this code, i get a warning as :**

> this file has been moved to util/delay.h

the code is perfectly fine.
**when i tried to build this project, i get some errors like,**

```
Error :     multiple definition of 'lcd_set_4bit'                       
Error:      Disabling relaxation: it will not work with multiple definitions       
warning:    "This file has been moved to <util/delay.h>. [-Wcpp]"   
Error:      multiple definition of 'lcd_wr_command' in file delay.h           
Error:      multiple definition of 'lcd_init' in file delay.h    
Error:      multiple definition of 'lcd_wr_char' in file delay.h                                          
Error:      multiple definition of 'lcd_home' in file delay.h   
Error:      multiple definition of 'lcd_string' in file delay.h   
Error:      multiple definition of 'lcd_cursor' in file delay.h   
Error:      multiple definition of 'lcd_print' in file delay.h                    

Error:      recipe for target 'project6.elf' failed   
Error:      ld returned 1 exit status
```

please somebody help me get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The function declarations and definitions must be in separate .h/.c files for Atmel Studio.  At least, that fixed this error for me.